# Send user to transaction detail page on Square website from my application

Tags: square-connect

I have an integration made for my software. I want to be able to link the user to the transaction in their Square account for easier access. I only have been using the Sandbox which does not provide a way to see the actual test transactions. What does the URL to a transaction in Square look like?

Comment: An example of a Transactions HTTP Request is viewable in our Developer Doc: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-transactions. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://squareup.com/dashboard/sales/transactions/bqrErYeG9q3rIAFGAxO4FIveV/by-unit/75MBQ5SS3SKJK
```

The first id is a `transaction_id` and the second id my `location_id`. Keep in mind that what you are looking to do (deep linking into Square Dashboard), is not something that is officially supported, so it might change at anytime without warning.